# How to CPI into token_metadata_program with optional accounts

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, cpi, mpl-token-metadata

I am aiming to Cross Program Invoke the [transfer](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/main/programs/token-metadata/program/src/instruction/mod.rs#L723) method of token_metadata_program.

The method takes optional parameters:

```
...
    #[account(6, optional, name="edition", desc="Edition of token asset")]
    #[account(7, optional, writable, name="owner_token_record", desc="Owner token record account")]
    #[account(8, optional, writable, name="destination_token_record", desc="Destination token record account")]
    #[account(9, signer, name="authority", desc="Transfer authority (token owner or delegate)")]
...
```

How can I properly forge the CPI call to skip the optional accounts?

What I have so far:

```
pub fn initialize_auction_2(ctx: Context<InitializeAuction2> ... ) {
    ...

    let transfer_accounts = MetadataTransfer {
            token: ctx.accounts.signer_withdraw_wallet.to_account_info(),
            token_owner: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
            destination: ctx.accounts.treasury_token.to_account_info(),
            destination_owner: ctx.accounts.treasury.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.treasury_mint.to_account_info(),
            metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            edition: ctx.accounts.edition.to_account_info(),
            owner_token_record: ctx.accounts.owner_token_record.to_account_info(),
            destination_token_record: ctx.accounts.destination_token_record.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
            payer: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            sysvar_instructions: ctx.accounts.sysvar_instructions.to_account_info(),
            spl_token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            spl_ata_program: ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
            authorization_rules: ctx.accounts.auth_rules.to_account_info(),
            authorization_rules_program:ctx.accounts.auth_rules_token_program.to_account_info(),
        };

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            transfer_accounts,
            signer_seeds
        );

        token_metadata_transfer(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
```

Where token_metadata_transfer is defined as:

```
pub fn token_metadata_transfer<'info>(
    ctx: CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, MetadataTransfer<'info>>,
    amount: u64,
) -> Result<()> {
    let ix = build_mpl_token_metadata_instruction_with_builder(
        ctx.accounts.authority.key,
        ctx.accounts.authority.key,
        ctx.accounts.token.key,
        ctx.accounts.destination_owner.key,
        Some(*ctx.accounts.destination.key),
        ctx.accounts.metadata.key,
        ctx.accounts.payer.key,
        None,
        ctx.accounts.mint.key,
        None,
        Some(*ctx.accounts.edition.key),
        amount,
    );

    solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
        &ix, 
        &[
            ctx.accounts.token.clone(), // Token account
            ctx.accounts.token_owner.clone(), // Token account Owner
            ctx.accounts.destination.clone(), // Destination token account
            ctx.accounts.destination_owner.clone(), // Destination token account owner
            ctx.accounts.mint.clone(),  // Mint
            ctx.accounts.metadata.clone(), // Token Metadata
            ctx.accounts.edition.clone(), // Edition
            ctx.accounts.owner_token_record.clone(), // Owner token record
            ctx.accounts.destination_token_record.clone(), // Destination token record
            ctx.accounts.authority.clone(), // Authority
            ctx.accounts.payer.clone(), // Payer
            ctx.accounts.system_program.clone(), // System Program
            ctx.accounts.sysvar_instructions.clone(), // Sysvar Instructions
            ctx.accounts.spl_token_program.clone(), // SPL Token Program
            ctx.accounts.spl_ata_program.clone(), // System Program
            ctx.accounts.authorization_rules.clone(), // Authorization rules
            ctx.accounts.authorization_rules_program.clone(), // Authorization rules program
        ], ctx.signer_seeds).map_err(Into::into)
```

If I try to comment one of the Optional accounts from the accounts list passed to `invoke_signed` the mpl_token_metadata complains that:

`Instruction references an unknown account <pubkey>`

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

The MPL token metadata program exports a builder that you can use to create your CPI instruction.

Check how the Candy Machine uses it: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine/blob/main/programs/candy-guard/program/src/guards/nft_payment.rs#L149

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. I am drawing inspiration from that at the moment. From the code, it's calling spl_transfer if the token is non programmable. 
Although the mpl_token_metadata::transfer should take care of that as well if used correctly.

Anyhow, appreciate the answer, I am RO as well, hmu on telegram @danielpavel19